# RestEasy Client proxy throwing error java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to xxx class

Tags: java, jboss, resteasy

I am creating restEasy proxy client through below code :

```
Service service =  ProxyFactory.create(Service.class, UriBuilder.fromUri(host).path("casino-adapter/").build().toString(), client);
```

Now when i am calling method from this service it is throwing java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to xxx class.

And this is not occuring every time . Normally it works fine. However sometime it fails when it is tested under heavy load.